# How to replace a string in a file you cannot fully read due to encoding

Tags: python, encoding, bios

I am currently trying to make a script to replace strings in my BIOS image to change settings. Although, my python script does not work due to it not being able to read the whole BIOS image, here is the error:

```
      File "c:\Users\redacted\Desktop\c\redacted\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    for line in file:
  File "C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\fileinput.py", line 256, in __next__      
    line = self._readline()
  File "C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\fileinput.py", line 389, in _readline     
    return self._readline()
  File "C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode  
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 131: character maps to <undefined>
```

and here is the code currently:

```
import fileinput
filename = "Bios.rom"
text_to_search = "GGDA5C1ZQHHCYB8KWV"
replacement_text = "MEKJQAD0IXT19Y8DSN"

with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')
```

The expected result is it can edit ASCII and HEX strings in the BIOS image, any help in the right direction is needed.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput), you can provide an encoding when opening the file: `fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak', encoding='utf-8')`. You'll have to figure out what the actual encoding is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's a binary file. As the rom file does not only contain utf-8 characters, normal read-file methods fail.

This should probably work:

```
filename = "Bios.rom"
text_to_search = b"GGDA5C1ZQHHCYB8KWV" #Binary
replacement_text = b"MEKJQAD0IXT19Y8DSN" #Binary

with open(filename, 'rb') as file: #read binary (instead of utf-8 encoding) 
    content = file.read()
content = content.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text)

with open("Output.rom", 'wb') as file: #Write binary
    file.write(content)
```